# How to handle this layout using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I need a solution to handle my layout,
I use the id for the button it is very troublesome.
i think i will create it same many tab, when user click show  only a cost of product

```css
.product{
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  background:#efefef;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
.product .img{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:#aaa;
}

.cost{
  padding:20px 0;
  font-size:16px;
}
.btn{
  padding:5px 10px;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}

.active_btn{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="cost">100000đ</div>
  <div class="cost hide">200000đ</div>
  <button type="button" class="btn">10ml</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">20ml</button>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="cost">100000đ</div>
  <div class="cost hide">150000đ</div>
  <div class="cost hide">250000đ</div>
  <button type="button" class="btn">10ml</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">20ml</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">50ml</button>
</div>
```

A product have other cost,
I need a solution to handle my layout,
I use the id for the button but it is very troublesome.

Comment: Please describe the problem in details, there's no clue in the post what you actually want the code to do.

Comment: It's totally unclear what you are asking here

Comment: meaning:
i used id for all button 
and id for all cost, then write a
 function showCost(button id){
get index button and show cost
}

butit is very troublesome,
so i need a optimal design and simple then i will code js for layout
a product have many choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a unique identifier to tie each button to each price then toggle them using  add/remove class

i used a attribute on the button and a class on the price to tie them

```js
$('button').click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
$(this).closest('.product').find('.cost').addClass('hide');
$(this).closest('.product').find('.for'+id).removeClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.product{
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  background:#efefef;
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
.product .img{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:#aaa;
}

.cost{
  padding:20px 0;
  font-size:16px;
}
.btn{
  padding:5px 10px;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}

.active_btn{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="cost for10">100000đ</div>
  <div class="cost for20 hide">200000đ</div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-id="10">10ml</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-id="20">20ml</button>
</div>

<div class="product">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="cost for10">100000đ</div>
  <div class="cost for20 hide">150000đ</div>
  <div class="cost for50 hide">250000đ</div>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-id="10">10ml</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-id="20">20ml</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-id="50">50ml</button>
</div>
```